# Is the laravel method "inRandomOrder()" truly random?

Tags: php, laravel, random

My team is building a raffle application where the RNG (random number generator) must be truly random so that it can be approved by the Secretary of State to run online raffles.

```
$winner = $raffle->entries()->inRandomOrder()->first();
$winning_user = $winner->user()->first();
```

This is how the code has been implemented and I just wanted to see if anyone could give feedback as to how "truly random" this is, or if we should be approaching this in a different way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is random but not unique if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Can you point to any resources or research you have done to investigate how this RNG is implemented, which may point to how random it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `inRandomOrder` is defined in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` class like so

```php
/**
 * Put the query's results in random order.
 *
 * @param  string  $seed
 * @return $this
 */
public function inRandomOrder($seed = '')
{
    return $this->orderByRaw($this->grammar->compileRandom($seed));
}
```

So it just orders by a row that is `compileRandom` which is defined in `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar`

```php
/**
 * Compile the random statement into SQL.
 *
 * @param  string  $seed
 * @return string
 */
public function compileRandom($seed)
{
    return 'RANDOM()';
}
```

So this is just an SQL statement on **LIMITED DATASET** ordered randomly

If `$raffle->entries()->count()` is 1 then it's 1/1 (100%) probability chance of getting the same value next round, if 50 then 1/50 and so on, you can't trust it not to return the same value (tho unlikely for huge datasets)

for example

```php
App\User::inRandomOrder()->toSql();
```

Simply results in

```
select * from `users` order by RAND()
```

So it's not really up to Laravel, it's up to the SQL engine you're using (MySQL or Postgres...etc)

For MySQL here's what they say

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version.

So you can't trust it to be truly random

If you want a really random number or string with a low chance of duplicating, I would recommend trying an `md5` or even better a `bcrypt` hash

Hope this helps